# query a json key in postgres json field

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Say I have in Postgres stored in JSON field called “data” like this

```
{
    "CUSTA": {
        "name": "Customer A",
    },
    "CUSTB": {
        "name": "Customer B",
    },
    "CUSTC": {
        "name": "Customer C",
    }
}
```

How can I query to return the record that contains the key “CUSTA” ? or even better the value of “CUSTA” which is "name": "Customer A"

trying to do something like this but obviously i cant use the keyword key

```
SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE data->>key = 'CUSTA';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select '{
    "CUSTA": {
        "name": "Customer A"
    },
    "CUSTB": {
        "name": "Customer B"
    },
    "CUSTC": {
        "name": "Customer C"
    }
}'::json#>>'{CUSTA}';
           ?column?
------------------------------
 {                           +
         "name": "Customer A"+
     }
(1 row)
```

note: you have trailing commas after name:customer x, which is not proper json.  For your query, you would probably do something like:

```
select data#>>'{CUSTA}' from invoices;
```

or, if data isn't already a json field:

```
select data::json#>>'{CUSTA}' from invoices;
```

I don't understand why any invoice would have more than one customer though.

-g

Comment: thanks, that works, actually its not invoice but customer table. so this is the actual sql statement - select data::json#>>'{CUSTA}' from customers; BTW, if i wanted to get the row with all the fields how do i do that ?

Comment: this works "select id,company_id, data::json#>>'{CUSTA}' from customers;" but it has this unknown column ?column?

Comment: add as mycolumn after the '{CUSTA}' to rename the column, like: "select id,company_id, data::json#>>'{CUSTA}' as mycolumn from customers;"