# Filter Django queryset for a dict value

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I have a queryset of `Products` with `JSONField` `attributes` containing `dict`

```
class Product(models.Model):
attributes = JSONField(
    pgettext_lazy('Product field', 'attributes'),
    encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder, default={})
```

I want to filter `Products` where `attributes['12'] == '31'`

Following one works:

`qs.filter(attributes__contains={'12': '31'})`

Following one does not:

`qs.filter(attributes__12='31')`
Is this something I can achieve with `PostgreSQL` or should I move it to ES?

EDIT:
<s>Unfortunately I cannot use first solution, as this `dict` may contain more keys.</s>

First solution works well. Given we have:

```
product.attributes = {'333': ['6', '1']}
```

We can filter it out by:

```
Product.objects.filter(attributes__contains={'333': ['6']}
```

etc. Totally overlooked it.

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697540/query-a-json-key-in-postgres-json-field), Postgres does support it, but I'm not sure if / how Django achieves this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the second format, i.e. `qs.filter(attributes__key='value')`.

Your issue in this case, as [explained in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield), is that when using an integer as a key in a JSON query, that key will be used as the index of an array, thus it's interpreted as `attributes[12]` instead of `attributes['12']`.

As long as you stick to string keys, you should be fine.

An example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    json = JSONField(default=dict)


p = MyModel.objects.create(json={'0': 'something', 'a': 'something else'})

MyModel.objects.filter(json__0='something') # returns empty queryset
MyModel.objects.filter(json__a='something else') # returns the object created above
```